SQS lambda trigger not working as expected
The scenario is this: When my process start I send around 3k messages to a queue in SQS. From there I have a lambda that I want to pick 500 of those messages and process them, then take the next 500 messages and so on until the queue is empty. Since the lambda that processes the messages has to talk to a very slow API I can't use concurrent lambda executions, otherwise I will reach the limits on that API.
The problem that I'm seeing is that sometimes the lambda starts picking 500 messages but in the next execution picks less than 200 and the next execution it picks even less and so on, instead of picking 500 everytime.
Maybe I misunderstanding something in the settings. How can I achieve this behaviour?
These are my settings:
Lambda:
ProcessMessages:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Timeout: 600
      CodeUri: process_messages/
      Role: !Sub ${ConsumerLambdaRole.Arn}
      Handler: app.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.8
      ReservedConcurrentExecutions: 1
      Architectures:
        - x86_64
Queue:
  ProcessMessagesQueue:
    Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
    Properties:
      QueueName: 'processMessages'
      DelaySeconds: 0
      VisibilityTimeout: 900
      RedrivePolicy:
        deadLetterTargetArn: !GetAtt DLmessages.Arn
        maxReceiveCount: 10

EventSource:
  SendMessageToLambda:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::EventSourceMapping
    Properties:
      BatchSize: 500
      Enabled: true
      EventSourceArn: !GetAtt ProcessMessagesQueue.Arn
      FunctionName: !GetAtt ProcessMessages.Arn
      FunctionResponseTypes: 
        - "ReportBatchItemFailures"
      MaximumBatchingWindowInSeconds: 20
    
Lambda:
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    failed_messages = []
    records = event['Records']
    for record in records:
        try:
            ... process message ...
        except Exception as e:
            failed_messages.append({"itemIdentifier": record['messageId']})
    sqs_batch_response = {}
    sqs_batch_response['batchItemFailures'] = failed_messages
    return sqs_batch_response



As John said below that is standard SQS behavior.  But since you didn't include code on how you're processing messages it's not possible to help you fix it.

Yes, that is the behaviour of AWS Lambda and Amazon SQS. You won't be guaranteed that Lambda will receive the maximum number of messages from the SQS queue.
It is not possible to change this behaviour.

So to have a better chance of getting all my messages processed before they reach the DLQ should I just increase the max receive count on the redrive policy and hope for the best? :v
I mean, I know I can reprocess the messages once they got into the DLQ but I was hoping I could just keep that one for real failed messages.

Are you saying that messages are hitting the DLQ because the Lambda function is not processing them quickly enough? The redrive policy is based on maxReceiveCount, so simply waiting for a Lambda function shouldn't cause it to go to the DLQ. However, the way that Lambda polls from SQS can be a bit mysterious, so please let us know if this actually is the behaviour you are experiencing.

this is the behaviour im having: I have 3k messages in the queue, then all 3k messages change to "in-flight" messages, from there the lambda takes 500 messages as expected. After some time I have 2500 messages available in the queue, then those 2500 messages change to "in-flight" and a lambda gets triggered again, this time it takes only 300 messages. Then the queue will have 2200 messages available, and then the process start again and again. It appears that the lambda takes less and less messages everytime, and if the unprocessed messages reach the maxReceiveCount they go to the DLQ.

added the lambda code.

If your issue is to limit the number of requests for an AWS Lambda function, you can adjust the concurrency settings.
Each instance of your execution environment can serve an unlimited number of requests. In other words, the total invocation limit is based only on the concurrency available to your function.
The reserved concurrency restricts the maximum number of concurrent invocations for that function. Synchronous requests arriving in excess of the reserved concurrency limit will fail with a throttling error.
Configuring reserved concurrency for a function

I think I'm limiting the concurrency correctly, the issue comes when the lambda seems to be picking less and less messages everytime it runs.
